# error with keycloak /opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 47: KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL

Tags: docker, keycloak

after run command  docker-compose up with this configuration

compose.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
      driver: local

services:
  bubblesassurance-postgres-keycloak:
    container_name: bubblesassurance-postgres-keycloak
    image: postgres
    volumes:
    - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - bubblesassurance-network
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=keycloak
      - POSTGRES_USER=keycloak
  bubblesassurance-keycloak:
    container_name: bubblesassurance-keycloak
    image: jboss/keycloak
    depends_on:
      - bubblesassurance-postgres-keycloak
    networks:
      - bubblesassurance-network
    environment:
      - DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES
      - DB_ADDR=bubblesassurance-postgres-keycloak
      - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
      - DB_USER=keycloak
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  bubblesassurance-postgres-api:
    container_name: bubblesassurance-postgres-api
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - bubblesassurance-network
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=bubblesassurance
      - POSTGRES_USER=api
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=BonMatinMatin      
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
networks:
  bubblesassurance-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I have this error in consol but it's the first time I have that

```
bubblesassurance-keycloak             | Added 'admin' to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json', restart server to load user
bubblesassurance-keycloak             | /opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 47: KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: unbound variable
```

after that Exit with code 1

but I can't understand my trouble please help me

Comment: What version of the jboss/keycloak image are you using? Your issue appears related to a commit made to the docker-entrypoint.sh on the same day. See ["Fix unbound variables"](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/commit/ee9d9d1ff4f7e2bfaab713f82097d7971bd49c00#diff-8f2c471edf89dff2f216a5ee79d5b2ea)

Answer (score 0):

try adding `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL` to your `compose.yml` file, in the environment definitions:

```
      - DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES
      - DB_ADDR=bubblesassurance-postgres-keycloak
      - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
      - DB_USER=keycloak
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=''
```

If you look at the [`entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/master/server/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh) scipt, it is expecting `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL` to be set to something.... so, try setting it and let's see what happens.